# Using RDS instead of mysql containers in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I used this tutorial to install wordpress using kubernetes.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

It is working as expected. But I will prefer to use Amazon RDS instead of mysql pods. I am not sure what changes are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the wordpress deployment you just need to update the host and credentials for your amazon db

[image]

you don't need to deploy any of the mysql resources from the tutorial.